# Automatic updates paused because 'Metered' - yet it is NOT a metered connection

Tags: upgrade

**Ubuntu 20.04.2, using Mate desktop**

I was trying to check on the update status of one of my apps and found that Software is no longer doing automatic updates because of my 'Metered' connection and it suggests I can turn that preventative 'Off'. My Data connection is 'unlimited data' so it's sort of metered in that if the cell tower gets crowded it can throttle back the data rate but not specifically metered for charges. When I check my connection though, that 'Metered' setting is already 'Off'. So what do I do now to get 'Software' to show upgrades or even my current installed software as it's not showing that either, it just shows a blank white page.

[image: Screen shot of error message...]

**EDIT:**

```
nmcli -t -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.METERED dev show $(ip route list 0/0 | sed -r 's/.*dev (\S*).*/\1/g')

GENERAL.DEVICE:wlx1cbfce112175                                       
GENERAL.METERED:yes (guessed)
```

PS I use Mate desktop...the most recent...I think. And I should mention I'm using Visible cell network (Verizon) for unlimited data for one low monthly price, all the time. I didn't have this problem a couple three Ubuntu upgrades before present time.

Comment: Please edit your quesiton to show the complete output of `nmcli -t -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.METERED dev show $(ip route list 0/0 | sed -r 's/.*dev (\S*).*/\1/g')`. Reference troubleshooting from [LP#1781183](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1781183)

Comment: That window on the left was for your wifi connection, not cellular.  Are you using both?

Comment: In a manner of speaking, YES, I am using both. I have a unlimited Data plan for my cell phone. When connected to the phone network, I can make my phone a 'hot spot'. Then I attach my computer via wifi to the hot spot's SSID. Boom, unlimited data via wifi using my cell phone. Keep in focus the issue of Ubuntu behaving as though the 'Metered Connection...' is check marked when it is NOT.

Comment: Sometime between when I posted the above and today, something upgraded and fixed this problem. I did have to open Edit Connections,  choose my current connection, click the gear, than choose the General tab. The dialog is different now then it was before. Now 'Metered Connection' has a drop down with Yes, No, and Automatic and the default is Automatic and that's what I found it set at. Changed that to NO, disconnected than reconnected and Snap now works without giving the error message. So THANKS mystery coder.

Comment: @Jim_HiTek I  upvoted your question because I liked the comment about the way you solved it. Please post it as an answer to your own question.